# HTML5 table cell/row same width as others

Tags: css, html, html-table, width, cell

I have table with multiple rows, each row contains just one cell.
Rows below the first have arbitrary, unknown width.
The first row contains arbitrary (wrappable) text of unknown length/width.
I wish the (text in) the first row to take the same width as whatever width has been adopted by the rest of the table, and am struggling.

```
<table style="background-color: Green;">
  <tr>
    <td id="row1" style="background-color: Red;">
      <div>
    stackoverflow question stackoverflow question stackoverflow question stackoverflow question stackoverflow question stackoverflow
    question stackoverflow question stackoverflow question stackoverflow question stackoverflow question stackoverflow question
    stackoverflow question stackoverflow question stackoverflow question stackoverflow question stackoverflow question
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="row2">
      <div style="width: 500px; background-color: Blue;">
    CONTENT IS HERE, WITH SOME (UNKNOWN) WIDTH
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that the `<div style="width: 500px;>` is only there for illustration to give the subsequent table rows some width.  *I do not know how wide the table or its rows will be*.

In HTML5/Standards/IE9+ the first row expands to the width of the table's container.   I want the width allocated for the first row/cell to match whatever the width of the rest of the table happens to be, which is what happened in HTML4/Quirks/IE8-.  I am looking for an HTML5/CSS3 solution without having to resort to script.

The only thing I have found to "work" is if I set row1's td to have `width: 1px;` .  This seems to limit the first row's width, and then it expands to the table's width.  This works at "runtime", but at "designtime" in Visual Studio it renders with the text spilling onto many lines, one word per line, which is unworkable for me and makes me think this is not the way to do it.

Comment: can you show the same in fiddle?

Comment: Have you used `max-width` instead? This seems more like an issue with your IDE (yay Microsoft) as opposed to the HTML itself

Comment: @Era I wish I could, but cannot create an account in jsfiddle, as the "sign up" has 4 controls for me to fill in and no labels against any of them to say what is wanted (IE9, both "native" & "compatibilty view".... ) I'm working on it...

Comment: @ExtPro max-width against what?  And what value, given that I have no idea, as I keep saying the content is unknown/dynamic?

Comment: @ExtPro So far, it looks like you have saved my bacon!  Against the td, `max-width:1px` behaves the same at "runtime" as `width:1px`, and "works".  At (Visual Studio) "designtime": `width` always causes one word per line, which is unworkable; `max-width` in a simple case like my code above is ignored causing full width, which is bad, _but_ it seems to work just right with the rest of my tables' contents in practice, so I think it's going to suffice for me.

Comment: So, ignoring my "designtime" problems, is it "correct" to/would you use `max-width` on the td to cause it not to widen the table yet have its content widen to (rest of) table width?  If so, once I have done some more checking in a while, I will accept ExtPro's solution.

Comment: The subsequent content of the table cells will override the max-width property of the first cell as it becomes untenable. I dont like this kind of fix personally, but it may be a case of if it works it works..Have added it as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at using  `max-width:1px;` instead of `width`

Comment: Against the td, `max-width:1px` behaves the same at "runtime" as `width:1px`, and "works". At (Visual Studio) "designtime": `width` always causes one word per line, which is unworkable; `max-width` in a simple case like my code above is ignored causing full width, which is bad, but it seems to work just right with the rest of my tables' contents in practice, so I think it's going to suffice for me.

Answer (score 0):

why are you using div's in a table? 
Just set the the tables td to have a width in the css style sheet? 
Or
If you want to use div's why are you using a table especially when the table is only one field wide. then just set a border if required and width in the stylesheet.

Comment: The divs are an example, as I said, to show some width.  The content is arbitrary content.  I can remove the div from "row1" td and put the text directly into the td but the problem remains identical --- row1's td will not size to the width of whatever the (largest) is among the subsequent rows.

What "width" can I set (in a stylesheet or anywhere), given that I have said I don't know what the width is, and want it to be the width of the rest of the table's content?

Answer (score 0):

what if you put width:1px not in inline-style, but as an attribute on the first td

```
<td id="row1" style="background-color: Red;" width="1">
```

Comment: td width attribute is deprecated/removed in HTML5.  In any case, how does that differ from putting it into the style's width?